# How "Immediate" Work In MIPS Architecture?

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-architecture, immediate-operand

I just started learning MIPS32 architecture some weeks ago and while I was reading about constants in it, it said that I can add a number which is not in memory or in a register!

For example this:

```
aadi $s3,$s2,4
```

If the numbers should be in a reg to get calculated T then where does that number (which here is 4) come from? What is it represented of? When do we actually use it?

Comment: An immediate operand is stored in the instruction itself.  Read the MIPS instruction set reference for how it works on MIPS specifically.

Comment: And instructions are stored in memory..  So, when the processor fetches the instruction, it has the opcode, register names, and immediate field (when applicable).